# Entity Framework: how to select an int

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I need to select an integer value from a table:

```
int id = from s db.Table
         where s.Id == someParameter
         select s.intValueOfInterest;
```

That doesn't work. I tried this but it looks really ugly:

```
int id = int.Parse((from s db.Table
         where s.Id == someParameter
         select s.intValueOfInterest).ToString());
```

What would be the best way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
int id = (from s in db.Table         
         where s.Id == someParameter         
         select s.intValueOfInterest).First().Value;
```

if intValueOfInterest is nullable, or

```
int id = (from s in db.Table         
         where s.Id == someParameter         
         select s.intValueOfInterest).First();
```

if it's not.

Linq is assuming that there could be more than one result (even though you're querying against the Primary Key), so we use .First() to return a single element, and the .Value deals with a null (actually, it'll fail if it is null).

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourval = (from s in db.Table
     select s.intValueOfInterest).First(p=>p == someParameter);
```